# Custom popup dialog box in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

I want to create a custom popup dialog box like the attached image in jquery mobile. The requirement is like I don't want the dialog box in rectagnular shape. I want to put "V" kind of shape at the bottom of the dialog box. Can someone please provide the solution or idea for the same.

[image: Custom popup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit jQuery mobile documentation page here;

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/

Here you can see a **Dialogue** button. Click there and you can see the solution you are looking for. You may then customize it using CSS.

Visit the page and start working on it.

Here is the design for your popup box

You may design html like

```
<div id="box">message
    <div id="arrow">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpMXb.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

and set CSS like

```
body{
    background:#0066CC;
}
#box{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#arrow{
    display:block;
    margin-top:170px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
#arrow img{
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FppzR/

Comment: Hi I have visited that site, but I don't want the dialog box to be in rectangular shape, I want to add one "v" kind of shape at the bottom of dialog box. Can you provide any idea for that?